# subalgebra of invariants for a reductive subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, reductive-groups, homogeneous-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Trying to understand some tannakian reconstruction, I've stumbled about the following problem in invariant theory. I guess it's something classical, or at least already studied, but I wasn't able to find relevant references.

We start with a reductive group $G$ over an alg.closed field of characteristic 0, and pick a reductive subgroup $H$. For example $G=\PGL(2)$ and $H$ the maximal torus $T$.

The Peter–Weyl theorem for $G$ says that we have a canonical (through matrix coefficients) decomposition as $G\times G$ representations
$$\mathcal O(G) = \bigoplus_{\text{$V$ irred}} V\boxtimes V^*.$$

Given a fixed irreducible representation $W$ of $G$, we consider inside the algebra of invariants $A:=\mathcal{O}(G)^H$ the subalgebra $B_W$ generated by $W^H\boxtimes W^*$.
The algebra $A$ is filtered so one could imagine that even if one takes invariants for a very large irreducible representation, they might combine to give invariants of smaller degree, generating all of $A$.
The subalgebra $B_W\subset A$ has also an action of $1\times G$, hence we get a $G$-equivariant morphism of schemes
$G/H=\Spec(A)\to \Spec(B_W)$.

Hence some questions (assuming $G$ is adjoint):

1. Is it true that $B_W$ is equal to $A$ for every irreducible $W$? (I suspect no but I can't get a straight answer even for $\PGL(2)$.)
2. Can we characterize the irreps $W$ for which we have $B_W=A$? I.e., which are the highest weights for which this works?
3. If we extend the definition of $B_W$ to any representation (naïvely: take the subalg of $A$ generated by all $W_i^H\boxtimes W_i^*$ for $W_i$ an irreducible summand of $W$) then can we characterize the irreducibles that we need inside $W$ in order to have $B_W=A$?
4. Is there a nice way of describing $B_W$? For example, is it a homogeneous variety? (I.e., is the map $G/H\to \Spec(B_W)$ surjective?) If so, how do we find the subgroup it corresponds to?
5. The image of $G/H\to \Spec(B_W)$ is a homogeneous variety, so there must be a subgroup of $G$, say $H_W$, containing $H$ such that this image is isomorphic to $G/H_W$. Can we describe the group $H_W$ in some way?

Remarks:

i) Question 1. as formulated has negative answer for $H=T\le \operatorname{SL}(2)=G$: any even-dimensional representation has no $T$-invariants. This is the reason I wanted to restrict the question to adjoint groups.
Question 1 has positive answer for $T\le \PGL(2)$ and $W=L_2$ the adjoint representation.

ii) I didn't find a concrete description of the Peter-Weyl decomposition even for $\PGL(2)$:
$$\mathcal{O}(\PGL(2)) = \bigoplus_{n\ge 0} L_{2n}\boxtimes L_{2n}^*.$$
Namely, is there a nice (explicit?) way of giving a base of $L_{2n}\boxtimes L_{2n}^*$ inside $\mathcal{O}(\PGL(2))$ such that one can figure out what the algebra $B_{L_{2n}}$ looks like? Notice that the natural map I'm talking about $V\boxtimes V^*\to \mathcal{O}(G)$ is matrix coefficients. I'm asking if one can describe its image in such detail as to figure out the answer of the above questions.

Comment: When you take $H$-invariants, the $H$-action is by translation? \\ (3) I changed $W_i$ to $W_i^H$, as seemed desired. \\ (5) is "*If* the image is a homogeneous variety", right (since it seems from (4) that you don't know that it is?). \\ For (ii), the basis of matrix coefficients seems like a good place to start; does it not work?  (Your notation there specifies $W$ but suppresses $H$; I guess you are talking still about $H = T$.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, the action is by translation! For (5) the image of a homogeneous variety through an equivariant map is still homogeneous. I don't know if the image is everything though...
Indeed, matrix coefficients is the natural map to get $V\boxtimes V^*\to \mathcal{O}(G)$ but I got drowned in computations and I couldn't figure out something nice.